# Modify GTX 580 fan speeds in bios

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, temperature, firmware

I have stock overclocked GTX 580s which run so hot that the driver crashes. I can dial up the fan manually using Nvidia Inspector. That fixes the problem, but i have to tinker around all the time and listen to the fan more often than necessary.

So, I tried loading my VBIOS into NiBiTor, but everything was greyed out. Is there any other way to edit fan/temp thresholds in the VBIOS and flash it back please?

Comment: Nah, dont want to RMA the cards. I have yhree stacked on each other so the cooling just isnt good enough at stock fan speeds. Just want to up them a couple percent and foget it.

Comment: Hmm. Why don't you mod your case? I mean screwing holes for 8 or 12cm fans and then install like 2*12cm fans near your VGAs. With this 'hack', you'll get enough air pushed into your case. Seriously, it's better than any software / modiying fans. It requries only basic skills to do so. :)

Comment: Because i have the Corsair Obsidian 800D with good airflow and lots of fans already.

Comment: I also made a very professional drawing about the technical side of things: http://noob.hu/2011/10/21/asdf.jpg (Note: The blue X may show the perfect place for the fan(s).)

Comment: Thanks, but i still believe this is a software bug as 85% duty cycle (maximum) is never ordered by the automatic control even though the cards run hot. Hence i want to fix the root cause, not introduce more noise into my room. (System will run quieter in idle than with an extra fan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows 7 then my first thought would be to leave the BIOS as is and use something to control the fan to how you want. I have been using [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) for a long time to control the fan speeds on my ATI 5850, it works along a line graph and plotting which is real nifty.

Comment: Does it support modifying the automatic fan curve? I already know how to manually control the fan as stated in my first post. I dont want to have to change fan speeds all day, just set them once and forget it.

Comment: @MaciejSwic - In order to do that, I think you may need to disassemble the BIOS, write a new one, write it the GPU. The warranty will be void, and there is a slight chance of bricking the card(s).

Comment: No MSI Afterburner does allow specifying a fan curve with a set it and forget it setting so it will act as if your GPU BIOS fan profiles have been modified without touching your GPU BIOS

Comment: @Shiki I inderstand that and I'm perfectly fine with that. I modified the VBIOS for my 7800 GTX before, but i dont remember which tool i used.

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal ok then, didn't expect that but Ill try it.

Comment: Was able to find the fan curve, nice touch from MSI. I noticed that the app says powered by Rivatuner, does Rivatuner also have a fan curve? Id prefer using that instead of the branded version. Hate skins like the MSI one.

Comment: No Rivatuner does not have the fan curve, MSI Afterburner is made by the same person that made Rivatuner, and has implemented the Rivatuner engine in MSI Afterburner after being employed by MSI to make the utility. The application is built on top of and improved on Rivatuner